# Adding data to an array of struct

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to add/remove data from an array of a defined struct.

```
struct process
{
    public int Proc_Id;
    public int Proc_BurstTime;
    public int Proc_Priority;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "ID: " + Proc_Id.ToString() + " Time: " + Proc_BurstTime.ToString() + " Prior: " + Proc_Priority.ToString();
    }
};

readonly process[] ProcessList = new process[]
{
    new process{ Proc_Id = 1, Proc_BurstTime = 3000, Proc_Priority = 1},
    new process{ Proc_Id = 2, Proc_BurstTime = 5000, Proc_Priority = 2},
    new process{ Proc_Id = 3, Proc_BurstTime = 1000, Proc_Priority = 3},
    new process{ Proc_Id = 4, Proc_BurstTime = 10000, Proc_Priority = 4}
};
```

I see it is readonly (based on some Google searches, I have no other option.
I can modify the data, but how do I go about adding data to the ProcessList?  I've tried ProcessList.Add(~), but that's not working.

Basically, what I'm exactly trying to do is populate this array of structs into a ListBox control.  I have been able to initially populate it by using DataSource, I've also been able to modify the contents and "re-datasource" it to update the ListBox.  However, I cannot ADD or REMOVE processes.  Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: You've declared it readonly, but why? What did Google tell you and more importantly, what were you asking it?
Also, is there a reason you have to use structs? I'd really recommend using a List<T> instead where T is a class. If these structs are being provided to you from a source over which you have no control, you can always map them into a class object with a simple function...

Comment: You can't add elements to an array, you need to use a list or create a new array with 5 elements and copy over the 4 defined elements and add one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to use a collection.

A `List<T>` would do just fine.

```
var processes = new List<process>();
processes.Add(new process
{
    Proc_Id = 1, 
    Proc_BurstTime = 3000, 
    Proc_Priority = 1
});
```

Modifying your code a bit would result in this below.

```
List<process> ProcessList = new List<process>()
{
    new process {Proc_Id = 1, Proc_BurstTime = 3000, Proc_Priority = 1},
    new process {Proc_Id = 2, Proc_BurstTime = 5000, Proc_Priority = 2},
    new process {Proc_Id = 3, Proc_BurstTime = 1000, Proc_Priority = 3},
    new process {Proc_Id = 4, Proc_BurstTime = 10000, Proc_Priority = 4}
};
```

This collection type also has the `Add` method you are referring to in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `readonly` prevents the variable, `ProcessList` from being assigned a new list.  If you removed `readonly` you could create a new array with the new, desired size and copy the elements from the old array to it, then assign it to `ProcessList`.  This is unlikely what you really want to do.  The better solution would be, instead, to use a collection that allows you to add/remove elements. An array, once created, cannot have it's size changed.  A `List<T>` (or some other generic collection), is built to allow new elements to be added or existing elements to be removed, with the size adjusting to reflect the number of current elements.

```
readonly List<process> ProcessList = new List<process>
{
    new process { Proc_Id = 1, Proc_BurstTime = 3000, Proc_Priority = 1 },
    new process { Proc_Id = 2, Proc_BurstTime = 5000, Proc_Priority = 2 },
    new process { Proc_Id = 3, Proc_BurstTime = 1000, Proc_Priority = 3 },
    new process { Proc_Id = 4, Proc_BurstTime = 10000, Proc_Priority = 4 }
};
```